# Set Image as Header in Excel using Apache poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I've the code below to set Header for Excel using Apache-Poi

```
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
 HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");
 Header header = worksheet.getHeader();
 header.setCenter("Header");
```

Is that possible to set an Image(.jpg format) instead of String as a Header using Apache Poi,
ie,

```
Header header = worksheet.getHeader();
header.setCenter(image.jpg); // This is pseudo code
```

If there is a solution let me know.